# Refreshing parts of div within a jquery loaded div every few seconds

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Im making some sort of a slideshow system, and I use JavaScript/jQuery/PHP to loop through different slides. This is all working good, but within the slides (that are dynamically loaded into a fullpage div), I also want to refresh sections of the slide (the slides are split up in several boxes).

I use SetInterval to reload the sections every x seconds, however, when the slide changes, and after a while the same slide appears, these SetIntervals stack up, causing the sections to reload way too many times.

I've tried to confirm whether the element still existed with:

```
var refreshBox = setInterval(function(){ 
if ($('#box_<php id>').length > 0){
//Ajax/Refresh code    
}else{
clearInterval(refreshBox);
}   
}, ".$boxes_data['box_refresh']."000);
```

But that didnt work. The intervals still act up when the same slide reappears.

Any solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Already managed to fix it by creating a global array:

```
window.refreshBox=new Array();
```

Create interval within array:

```
refreshBox[".($boxes_data['box_id'])."] = setInterval(function(){
```

Delete interval from array:

```
clearInterval(refreshBox[".($boxes_data['box_id'])."]);
```